# How to turn off prettier in comb. with create-react-app?

Tags: reactjs, prettier

I have tried to empty the .prettierrc file:

```
{
}
```

But still when I run npm start it still comes up with a 'prettier' compilation error.

Answer (score 0):

-if u are using visual code , then you can simply go to the extension tab and disable it.

-or you can try 
npm uninstall prettier

-or last option(in case above didn't work)  remove node modules folder than try to install it through npm install so it will automatically update all the dependencies.